# FFmpeg ignores start time to trim audio file android

Tags: android, trim, android-ffmpeg

I am implementing FFmpeg to my android project.

I used [ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) to perform editing in audio and video files.

Now I am trying to trim my audio file using FFmpeg and FFmpeg ignores my start time for trimming.

I referred many posts like:

[Trim video with reference to a start time and end time using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360691/trim-video-with-reference-to-a-start-time-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg)

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/FFMPEG-for-android/

But still, I am facing the same issue.

Below is my ffmpeg command:

```
   String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-ss", "00:00:20", "-i", uploadFilePath , "-t", "30", editFilePath};
```

I also tried with

```
   String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-ss", "00:00:20", "-i", uploadFilePath, "-t", "30", editFilePath};
```

and

```
    String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-ss", "00:00:20", "-i", uploadFilePath, "-t", "30", editFilePath};
```

But FFmpeg trims my audio file from start time `00:00:00` to `00:00:30` always. It ignores my start time or `-ss` time

If any more file or info needed, plz mention in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I am posting  my own question, but it might help others in future.

In my question, I am passing initial time at beginning of command line so ffmpeg didnt recognize it.

Below is corking commands:

```
  String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", uploadFilePath, "-ss", "00:00:20" , "-t", "30", editFilePath}

  String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", uploadFilePath, "-ss", "20" , "-t", "30", editFilePath};
```